# rtweet giving error in rbind when collecting large numbers of tweets

Tags: r, rtweet

I'm using the rtweet package in R to pull tweets for data analysis.
When I run the following line of code requesting 18,000 tweets, everything works fine:

```
t <- search_tweets("at", n=18000, lang='en', geocode='-25.609139,134.361949,3500km', since='2017-08-01', type='recent', retryonratelimit=FALSE)
```

But when I try to extend this to 100,000 tweets I get an error message

```
t <- search_tweets("at", n=100000, lang='en', geocode='-25.609139,134.361949,3500km', since='2017-08-01', type='recent', retryonratelimit=TRUE)

Finished collecting tweets!
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
```

Why is this occurring and how do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: I think the issue lies with the retryonratelimit=TRUE

Comment: no issue when I request 36,000 tweets

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating to the dev version of rtweet. It fixed this issue for me.

```
devtools::install_github("mkearney/rtweet")
```